# Should i drink proteinshakes or eat proteinbars on my chilldays?

Tags: workout, protein, weight-gain, protein-shakes

I'm trying to gain weight and I bought a 'Rice & Protein' Lean Muscle Mass supplement.
I also made some healthy proteinbars which also have a bit of this supplement inside them.

I started a month ago at about 62Kg and i'm now 64.3Kg. I'm also 1m74. I'm 22 Years old.

I work out 2 days a week, Full body exercises (90% upper body), Mostly i'll go to the gym Wednesday or Thursday and on Sunday. Now I was wondering, should i be taking any protein shakes or bars on the days I'm resting?

Comment: Exercising twice a week won't give you your desired results, even though they are full body exercises. You rest for 5 days and exercise on 2; that's a lot of resting.

Comment: Full body exercises that are 90% upper body? Just because you stand on your legs while doing curls doesn't make that a full body exercise.

Comment: The statement that 2 times/wk is insufficient is not absolute. If you are training with heavy weights to failure, 2 times/wk is more than enough for strength and mass gains.

Comment: Also, on your question, it _is_ important to get sufficient protein even on your off days as you will continue to build muscle if you worked out hard enough. The premium you pay for protein powders is mostly worth it because of the quick absorption after training so if you can get enough protein from regular food on off days there's no need. If you can't get enough normally, supplementing could be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Protein bars and shakes are supplements to normal food intake.

If you are tracking your calorie intake and expenditure (*which you should be for weight changes*), and you are finding your calorie intake requirements are making it hard for your regular diet to meet your macronutrient requirements, then there is no problem taking a supplement.

However, there is are numerous micronutrients in whole foods, such as vitamins and minerals, that are often not present in protein supplements, so only use them if you find you are not meeting your protein requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are attempting to gain lean muscle weight, supplementing your protein intake outside of your workout days is **probably a waste**. You should research clean and dirty bulking to get a better understanding of the influence of diet on weight gain.

Note that doing only 2 sessions a week is probably going to mean slow progress after the initial easy gains.

Comment: I just wanna gain weight.. anything I just don't wanna look fat ofcourse..!

Comment: You'll gain weight faster going to the gym more often rather than drinking shakes on days off.

Comment: But i need days to rest and i prefer full body workouts.. Is it OK to have only 1 day of rest in between sometimes ? I know I'll still be stiff then .. th'ts not good is it?

Comment: @Firebirdz Thats a separate question, so you make another question for that so people can give you proper answers.